# not printing count or average regardless of indentation

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a program that allows the user to enter grades until they enter a negative, and then output the number of passing grades and failing grades with the average. we aren't allowed to use the list function.

```
maxgrade = 100
mingrade = 0
passing = 0
failing = 0


while True:
    try:
        grade = int(input("Enter a grade: "))

        if 100 >= grade > 60:
            passing += 1
        elif grade <= 60:
            failing += 1
        if grade < 0:
            print("Invalid")


        if grade < mingrade:
            mingrade = grade
        if grade > maxgrade:
            maxgrade = grade

        total == grade
        count = passing + failing
        avg = total/count

        print("Average: ", avg)
        print("# Passing: ", passing)
        print("# Failing: ", failing)

    except:
             print("Invalid")
             break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in the comment, your usage of `try` and `except` is incorrect. `Try` and `except` are used in tandem to prevent errors from occurring. In your case however, I doubt that `try` and `except` is even needed. See below code for the workaround.

You also need to take into account your logic and code execution order. The following annotated code will work as specified.

```
# Assume the lowest and highest possible for max and min grades, respectively
max_grade = 0
min_grade = 100
grade_sum = 0
passing_count = 0
failing_count = 0

# Loop sentinel
running = 1

# Main loop
while running:

    # Input validation sentinel
    invalid_input = 1

    # Input validation loop
    while invalid_input:
        grade = input("Enter a grade: ")
        if grade.isnumeric():
            grade = int(grade)
            invalid_input = 0
        else:
            print("Please enter a number!")

    # Increment number of passing or failing grades
    if 100 >= grade > 60:
        passing_count += 1
    elif 60 >= grade >= 0:
        failing_count += 1
    else:
        running = 0

    # Update grade_sum
    grade_sum += grade        

    # Update min_grade and max_grade
    if grade < min_grade:
        min_grade = grade
    if grade > max_grade:
        max_grade = grade

# Calculate grade average
grade_avg = grade_sum / (passing_count + failing_count)

# Print results
print("Average: ", grade_avg)
print("# Passing: ", passing_count)
print("# Failing: ", failing_count)
```

Comment: @NicholasBrady The loop is broken at the `else` clause for grade validation. (`running = 0`)